# Text Wrap NSString in CGContextShowTextAtPoint

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, uiimage, drawing

I'm trying to have the NSString passed to CGContextShowTextAtPoint be wrapped so it doesn't get extended off the image. Here's my code:

```
int w = img.size.width;
int h = img.size.height;
CGFloat fMid = 14;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", fMid, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, fMid, text, strlen(text));


CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked]
```

Comment: If all you want is to render some text to an image, you don't need the CGContext machinery and could also just take a `UITextView` and call `renderInContext:` on it. Create the context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and take it from there.

Comment: @mvds I'm doing it like this because I need the text to be on the bottom of the image. This is the only way I have been able to do it.

Comment: I think you can still take the `UITextView` approach, it will be far easier and have less bugs. It sounds like you take custom input (otherwise you can hardcode the line break?). This means you will run into trouble when users start entering diacritical or other UTF8 characters, which will *not* display correctly (if at all) in "MacRoman" encoding... just my $.02

Comment: However, if you *do* want to go low level, you should use Core Text, but I have to warn you that it will be hard to get working the first time.

Comment: @mvds how would I do the 'UITextView' approach? Do you recommend any methods?

Comment: Like I said, create a `UITextView` with the desired properties, then: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, `[img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero]`, `[textview renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]`, and get the result with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`. Google & Apple docs are your friends.

Comment: @mvds I tried doing that but it's not creating a image or even drawing on it.

Comment: Maybe try some more things and google around, don't give up too easily. If you don't get it to work, ask a new question with your new source code.

Comment: @mvds I won't haha. I have some code that does wrap the text like I need it to but it just isn't positioned at the bottom.